# Order of request execution in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api

Let's say I have this route:

```
app.get('/sayHello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello User!')
})
```

If the server get 200 simultaneous requests (meaning, at the same exact moment) to this route,

how does Node.js decide which should be served first, second... etc.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Node.js handle simultaneous requests with one thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220878/how-does-node-js-handle-simultaneous-requests-with-one-thread)

Comment: From what I read there, my route above will get his own send and receive queue on the OS that runs Node, 
and Node will execute the 200 requests by the order of that queue?

Comment: the order is not important since the `event loop` try to resolve the result as response if the request has been finished and the callback has a return

Comment: Think about that like a queue of pepole with just one reception to handle their requests but `nodejs` uses more receptions for handling their requests

Comment: And these extra receptions are new threads? which share the CPU power with each other?

Comment: No, `nodejs` is single thread, the event loop do so if is not blocked with a high cpu computation

Comment: But the extra receptions RUN in the event loop, no? I

Comment: Read more details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855352/how-in-general-does-node-js-handle-10-000-concurrent-requests

Comment: Thank you for all the answers